# Count only by certain Condition

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to figure out for one of my fields being selected how I can include the site in the count only if the site is active.  But my syntax below is not right because I'm getting 40 for TotalSiteCount and 40 for TotalActiveSiteCount.  The actual count should be 3 for the TotalActiveSite count because we only have 3 that have a status of Active if I were to look at the table or do a seperate count on it outside this query I'm running here that includes the below.

```
, COUNT(*) OVER() as [TotalSiteCount]
, COUNT(CASE WHEN base.Status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) OVER() as [TotalActiveSitesCount]
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a SUM instead of COUNT

```
COUNT(*) OVER() AS [TotalSiteCount], 
SUM(CASE WHEN base.Status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER() 
     AS [TotalActiveSitesCount]
```

Alternatively, NULLs are not counted, if you use the count, so try

```
COUNT(*) OVER() AS [TotalSiteCount], 
COUNT(CASE WHEN base.Status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER() 
     AS [TotalActiveSitesCount]
```